# Best way to use MySQLi Prepared Statements in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm new to prepared statements. I have understood the use of it and how to use it. I want to know, where to place the statements and things like that. **Should I prepare one statement (or many) in each file I want to query the database?** Also, can you give me an example to use prepared statements in Procedural way?

I've tried doing this. It doesn't work though.

```
include 'db/connect.php';

$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = ?";
$i  = 5;
$statement = $connect->prepare($query);
$statement->bind_param('i', $i);
$statement->execute();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($statement)){
    echo $row['email'].'<br>';
}
```

Comment: You should prepare any statement that accepts user input, also you might want to use PDO instead of mysqli, but I forget why it was suggested as "better".

Comment: Best way to use MySQLi Prepared Statements in PHP is to use PDO prepared statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A procedural way... humm, been a long time since I did something procedural (strictly non OOP). I don't know why you want to limit yourself but I'll still leave PDO since it's best practice (from my POV)

> Should I prepare one statement (or many) in each file I want to query the database?

I think you should prepare as many queries as you need and encapsulate your functionality so you don't have to copy paste

#### in your `includes.php` file

define a function that may be used in many locations

```
/**
 * Get User by Id
 * @returns user object or null
 */
function getUserById(PDO $connection, $id) {
  $q = 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id`=?';
  $stmt = $connection->prepare($q);
  $stmt->execute(array($id));
  return $stmt->fetchObject();
}
```

#### in your `db/connect.php` file

setup your `PDO` connection (this is my personal recomendation, I'm biased)

```
// do not copy paste, check the manual to see for yourself how it is done
$dsn = 'mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$data;
$connection = new PDO($dsn,$user,$password);
```

#### usage

whenever you need to `get a user by his id` just pass your database connection (PDO object) and the `$id` to the function

```
// functionality has been encapsulated and may be reused
$user = getUserById($connection,$id);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll try learning PDO. I've been using PHP Procedural way all along. Never tried OOP. I guess its time to try out OOP now.

Comment: Please go ahead. Just remember that there are many, many ways to wrap your head around an issue/problem/requirement. There are many patterns to ascribe to. It'll take time before you can actually start thinking in objects, and even more so when you start thinking in abstract, interface, extensions, parents... of course procedural is also a solution, as long as your project is small and easily manageable

Comment: Will do! Thanks again!

By the way, can I instantiate the mysqli object and use it in my procedural scripts?

Comment: Yes, you can combine everything into an amalgam of spaghetti code if you want, I just don't recommend it. As for using objects inside your procedures, go ahead and do so. When you start getting used to it you may want to extend the thought process. Of course, benefits of this will become patent when you have to refactor/manage/extend/support your own codebase. Until then, take your time

Comment: You're really helpful! Thanks a lot! One last question, I have a site set up, where I have used mysql functions on almost every php file. Now, if I have to change it to MySQLi, do I have to change the mysql function in each page?

Comment: sorry for answering late. There are guides out there that can help you a lot with that. I would google for **migrating from mysql mysqli**. Be careful while you are doing it (make a backup of the site just in case). Happy holidays

Comment: Oh! I'll check on that! Thanks!

Comment: Don't know if I read your first paragraph wrong. But, it is highly recommended to use MySQLI prepared statements as it is more secure as it has a less change to get injected with code. It can happen, even if it's not public. It happened to me.

Answer (score 1):

I have added the complete code to create a single method for select prepared statement and insert prepared statement, Please follow the instruction and read all the comments.
 create database with the name 'test' and add the following query to create "users" table in the

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `users_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`users_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;


INSERT INTO `users` (`users_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`) VALUES
(1, 'daniel', 'martin'),
(2, 'daniel', 'martin');



<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
session_start();

 class mysqli_access extends mysqli{    

        private $ip1;
        private $dbconn;
        private $hostname = HST;    // hostname
        private $username = USR;    // username
        private $password = PWD;    // password
        private $dbname   = DBN;    // datbase name 


        function mysqli_access()
        {


                $ip= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                $ip1="ip_".str_replace('.', "", $ip);

                if(!is_resource($_SESSION[$ip1]))
                {
                        $this->dbconn = new mysqli($this->hostname,$this->username,$this->password,$this->dbname);
                        $_SESSION[$ip1] = $this->dbconn;
                        $dbconn = $this->dbconn;
                        if( $this->connect_error ) {
                                $this->Display_error('', $this->connect_errno, $this->connect_error, __FUNCTION__);
                        }
                }
                else {

                        $this->dbconn = $_SESSION[$ip1];        // success
                }

                return $this->dbconn;
        }


        function SelectPrepared($sql,$types,$params,$rows = '') 
        {
                $results = array();
                if ($stmt = $this->dbconn->prepare($sql)) {

                                if($types&&$params)
                                {
                                        $bind_names[] = $types;
                                        for ($i=0; $i<count($params);$i++) 
                                        {
                                                $bind_name = 'bind' . $i;
                                                $$bind_name = $params[$i];
                                                $bind_names[] = &$$bind_name;
                                        }
                                        $return = call_user_func_array(array($stmt,'bind_param'),$bind_names);
                                }
                                $stmt->execute(); /* execute query */
                                $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();
                                while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) { 
                                        $var = $field->name; 
                                        $$var = null; 
                                        $fields_arr[$var] = &$$var;
                                }

                                call_user_func_array(array($stmt,'bind_result'),$fields_arr);
                                if($rows == 1){

                                        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                                                $results = array();
                                                foreach($fields_arr as $k => $v)
                                                        $results[$k] = $v;
                                        }

                                }else{
                                        $i = 0;
                                        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                                                $results[$i] = array();
                                                foreach($fields_arr as $k => $v)
                                                        $results[$i][$k] = $v;
                                                $i++;
                                        }

                                }

                                return $results;

                }
        }


        public function InsertPrepared($tblName,$arrFieldNameValue,$replace_flag=0){
            $TableName = $tblName;
                if($replace_flag==0)  
                {
                        $sqlFirst ="INSERT INTO " . $TableName . "(";
                }
                if($replace_flag==1)
                {
                        $sqlFirst ="INSERT IGNORE INTO " . $TableName . "(";                        
                }
                if($replace_flag==2)
                {
                        $sqlFirst ="REPLACE INTO " . $TableName . "(";                      
                }

                $sqlSecond =" values(";
                $params = array();
                $types = '';
                while(list($key,$value) = each($arrFieldNameValue))
                {                   
                        $sqlFirst   = $sqlFirst . $key . ",";
                        $sqlSecond  = $sqlSecond . '?' . ",";
                        $params[]   = $value;
                        $types      = $types . $this->GetValType($value);
                }               

                $sqlFirst   = substr($sqlFirst,0,strlen($sqlFirst)-1) . ") ";
                $sqlSecond  = substr($sqlSecond,0,strlen($sqlSecond)-1) .")";
                $sql        = $sqlFirst . $sqlSecond;

                if ($stmt = $this->dbconn->prepare($sql)) {

                    if($types&&$params)
                    {
                            $bind_names[] = $types;
                            for ($i=0; $i<count($params);$i++) 
                            {
                                    $bind_name      = 'bind' . $i;
                                    $$bind_name     = $params[$i];
                                    $bind_names[]   = &$$bind_name;
                            }
                            $return = call_user_func_array(array($stmt,'bind_param'),$bind_names);
                    }
                    $stmt->execute(); /* execute query */

                }                       
                return mysqli_insert_id($this->dbconn); 
        }

        private function GetValType($Item)
        {

             switch (gettype($Item)) {
                case 'NULL':
                case 'string':
                    return 's';
                    break;

                case 'integer':
                    return 'i';
                    break;

                case 'blob':
                    return 'b';
                    break;

                case 'double':
                    return 'd';
                    break;
            }
            return 's';

        }
 }






class Model_NAME extends mysqli_access
{   
        function Model_NAME() { 
                $this->tablename = TABLENAME;
                $this->mysqli_access();
        }

        ##---------------------------- Custom function start from here -----------------#

        ## fetch settings values
        function getUserRow($id,$key) {
            $sql ="SELECT first_name,last_name FROM ".$this->tablename." WHERE first_name=? and users_id  = ?";
            $param = "si";
            $array_of_params[] = addslashes($key);
            $array_of_params[] = addslashes($id);
            $result= $this->SelectPrepared($sql,$param,$array_of_params,1);
            //last parameter 1 use if want fetch single row , other wise function will return multi dimensional array
            return $result;
        }


        ## fetch settings values
        function getUserRows($last_name) {
            $sql ="SELECT first_name,last_name FROM ".$this->tablename." WHERE last_name= ?";
            $param = "s";
            $array_of_params[] = addslashes($last_name);
            $result= $this->SelectPrepared($sql,$param,$array_of_params);
            //last parameter 1 use if want fetch single row , other wise function will return multi dimensional array
            return $result;
        }

        function addValue($Array) {
            return $this->InsertPrepared( $this->tablename , $Array);
        }
}       


// configuration
define('HST','localhost');
define('USR','root');
define('PWD','techmodi');
define('DBN','test');
define('TABLENAME','users');

$obj =  new Model_NAME();
$arr = array();
$arr['first_name'] = addslashes("daniel");
$arr['last_name'] = addslashes("martin");
$obj->addValue($arr); // for insert records

// after inserting get the records
$singleRow = $obj->getUserRow(1,'daniel'); // for select single records
$multiRow =$obj->getUserRows('martin'); // for select records
echo '<pre>';
echo '<br/>-------- Single Records -----------------<br/>';
print_r($singleRow);
echo '<br/>-------- Multiple Records-----------------<br/>';
print_r($multiRow);
?>
```

Comment: I just try to provide the demo of custom prepared statement form one single function.I didn't mentioned any where don't sanitize the input which are react with the sql query.any user who want avoid sql injection definitely he can customized the code.

Comment: I think so he has created a demo

Comment: yes, asim i just added a demo where user can create a multiple prepared statement from single function

Comment: if your code requires "customization" for such a vital part, it is utterly useless and harmful then.

Comment: @khanAsim a demo for what? for a code that noone should be using due to it's vulnerability and all the wrong practices used?

Answer (score 0):

Prepared statements prevent SQL Injection. PHP has the awesome extension "mysqli_" which is capable of doing prepared statements.

**Should I prepare one statement (or many) in each file I want to query the database?** 
The answer is yes. You should prepare statements in each file. (If you are doing the same query in several pages save your code in one file and include them when you need)

**It doesn't work though?**
Yeah, prepared statements usually make errors (we make errors when coding prepared statements.) So, knowing how to debug these is really useful. First of all, let's change your code like following.

```
include 'db/connect.php';

$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = ?";
$i  = 5;
$statement = $connect->prepare($query);
if (
  $statement &&
  $statement->bind_param('i', $i) &&
  $statement->execute()
) {
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($statement)){
    echo $row['email'].'<br>';
  }
} else {
  echo $connect -> error; // if you have an error in the query
  echo $statement -> error; // if you have an error in bind_param() or execute()
}
```

Nice! In this way, you can easily spot any error in your query or code. And, using if statement as above will help you to prevent many errors and continue the code only if the last one was successful.

There might be much better for this. But, with several years of experimenting, I found this method as the best one. Everything about this concept is written in this article:

[The Best Way to Perform MYSQLI Prepared Statements in PHP](https://developer.hyvor.com/php/prepared-statements)

Thanks!

Comment: no where on your hyperlink is there any mention of `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` ...for good reason.  I recommend that you practice what you preach.